# Selenium Multiple Values for find_elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In python I have:

```
driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='a')
```

How can I change this line to include also `b`, `c`, `d` etc... values?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='a', Value='b')...
```

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the source code of `find_elements`

```
def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
    """
    Find elements given a By strategy and locator. Prefer the find_elements_by_* methods when
    possible.

    :Usage:
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'foo')

    :rtype: list of WebElement
```

it takes only two args, so having this `driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='a', Value='b')` will not work.

However, to address the issue that you've reported here, I do not think `TAG_NAME` can be used as a locator **strategies**

Thus using **CSS** you could do this:

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tag_name[attributeA = 'valueA'][attributeB = 'valueB']")
```

**Using XPath:**

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tag_name[@attributeA = 'valueA' and @attributeB = 'valueB']")
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your question lets say you want to check multiple `HTML` tag using find elements. The best way you could do is `CSS_SELECTOR` or `XPATH`.

By Using CSS Selector let say you want check `div` or `span` or `input` tag

Your code should be like

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div, span, input")
```

By XPATH

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[self::div|self::span|self::input]")
```

Hope this example will help.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answerers indicated, `By.TAG_NAME` accepts only one aggument. In such cases to select elements with multiple `By.TAG_NAME` e.g. *`<a>`*, *`<b>`*, *`<c>`*, etc, you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a, b, c")
  ```
- Using *TAG_NAME* through *`lambda`* expression:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a") or driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "b") or driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "c"))
  ```